# Autocomplete not working with Better Exposed Filters + Views Table Filter

Tags: theming, views

everyone.
I'm using Drupal 7 with all modules updated to the last stable version.

I have a table view in which each column can be filtered through an exposed filter.
If I move the filters to the table header using better exposed filters and views table filter modules, the autocomplete feature stops working (both for entity reference fields and for fields for which I've enabled autocomplete with views autocomplete filter module).

Nothing happens while I'm typing (the throbber doesnt't move too), but with Chrome's network inspector I can see that the correct JSON objects are being retrieved.
I'm sure it's not a theme / css problem, as no element is created in the page and I've checked with different themes.

Has anyone experienced this behaviour?

Thanks